# why bash prompt won't update unless I call bash again

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion, bash-functions

I have this function that echoes the recent directory

```
funtion prompt_oldpwd() {

 local oldpwd="";

    # check if the $OLDPWD is set and not empty
    if [ ! -z "${OLDPWD}" ]; then

       # truncate $OLDPWD value and set it to oldpwd
       oldpwd="${OLDPWD##*/}";

    else

    return;

    fi

echo "${oldpwd}"; 
}
```

if the `$OLDPWD` variable is set and not null it prints the truncated value.

It works fine when I call the function inside the terminal but when use in a prompt like this:

```
export PS1="$(prompt_oldpwd)"
```

it actually prints the value in the prompt but if the `$OLDPWD` change it won't update the prompt unless I run bash again.. Why is it like that? and how do I make it that when the `$OLDPWD` change it should also update?

Comment: can I get a proper explanation why this question is getting downvoted?

Comment: Thnks.. I found the answer in that thread.. should i delete this now?